# The output of the fragment shader is not always shown correctly (a lot of details down below) (solution found)

Tags: c++, synchronization, shader, driver, vulkan

So, here's the deal: I am working on a game engine, for learning purposes, and this is kind of a hobby. The engine uses OpenGL and Vulkan. I'm currently working on the PBR renderer in Vulkan. It had been working for a long time, until I refactored it.

This is the problem: I have a few uniform buffers, and I wanted to test if I recieved them all correctly. But some of them were just incorrect, like the light colour, gamma, etc, where the output was pitch-black, while others, like the light position are shown correctly, with the right colour.

So I thought this could be a problem with the uniforms. I booted up RenderDoc, and it turns out that when capturing a frame, not only do I recieve every data correctly, but the result is correct on the swapchain image, so the problem is that either: the data is lost during presentation, or I present an incomplete image, and RenderDoc just waited long enough with the capture that it is correct.

So I assume have a synchronisation problem. The way this system works, is like this (almost entirely copied from vulkan-tutorial.com, except that it is factored into classes):

- I wait for the current frame's fence
- I aquire the next image, supplying a semaphore for this frame
- I recreate the swapchain if necessary
- I record this frame's command buffer (the rerecord is necessary because the context is changing dynamically)
- I reset this frame's fence
- I submit the work using a wait and signal semaphore
- I present the results using the signal semaphore from before as the wait semaphore
- I increase the current frame

There's one semaphore and fence per swapchain image.

Since this could easily be a driver or OS issue, here's my specs:
I'm working on Windows 10 Pro, 64 bit (build 19041), the GPU is a GTX 1060 3 GB, and my driver version is 456.71. The program is developed in Visual Studio 2019 Preview. I can link the GitHub repo or the RenderDoc capture.

So a quick recap: I recieve every uniform correctly, but some of them are shown as black (0,0,0 as a matter of fact, because adding 0.5 to it results in a gray colour), and some of them are shown correctly, but according to RenderDoc, the data is correct, and the swapchain image after capturing is correct, so the problem occours during presentation.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause the problem? Is it really the synchronisation? Could it be anything else? I don't think I can give a minimal reproducable example because the source code is quite large, and complicated, but if you want anything, ask, and I'll add the details.

Edit: It was not a synchronisation problem. The code for updating the uniform buffers overwrote the whole buffer, and I have no idea how RenderDoc showed correct data, and some descriptors still worked. So if you have a similar problem, double check the VkMapMemory(), memcpy(), and VkUnmapMemory() part of your code.

Comment: what loader do you use? glew  or what? and to tranfer buffers to card what function you'd used?

Comment: GLEW for windowing. I use the VulkanSDK to access validation layers and stuff. The uniforms are bascially using host coherent and visible memory, and are changed using memory mapping. (vkMapMemory, memset, vkUnmapMemory)

Comment: i didnt use vulkan stuff so idk

Comment: Do you have a version control system? You could try doing a git bisect to find the breaking commit. The do a git diff with the prior version to pinpoint the change that broke your code.

Comment: I am using GitHub. This is not that easy however. There was a huge update, where the Vulkan interface changed a lot, the shaders were changed, I eliminated the geometry shader from the PBR pipeline, and I actually didn't try to fix this issue, so this would be problematic.

Comment: Pseudocode is useless for debugging. Pseudocode shows only concepts\intentions, rarely shows bugs. All realistic source code is always large. How you do MCVE is by starting removing stuff or making one from scratch. Though, how do you choose the semaphore at the second step if you do not know which image it is? If you use the frame counter, how do you know you are allowed to reuse that specific present semaphore?

Comment: I found the solution. It was not a synchronisation problem, this is why the validation layers reported nothing. I'm gonna update the question to include the solution.